# Unable to run ansible playbook from Jenkins | But I am able to run the same playbook from terminal

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have a host machine which has ansible installed and a remote machine connected to the host. I am able to run the ansible playbook from within the terminal of the host machine and am able to ping and execute the playbook.

```
[centos@test-1234 ~]$ ansible all -m ping
10.10.1.94 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

and

```
[centos@test-1234 ~]$ ansible-playbook varfiles_1.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.10.1.94]

TASK [Test fact vs external variable comparison] *******************************
ok: [10.10.1.94 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.10.1.94                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

However, when I run the same playbook from jenkins via a shell build, I get the following error.

```
script: ansible-playbook -u centos /home/centos/varfiles_1.yml

Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4756676897950221446.sh
++ whoami
+ echo jenkins
jenkins
+ ansible-playbook -u centos /home/centos/varfiles_1.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [10.10.1.94]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file '/home/centos/varfiles_1.retry'.
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/centos/varfiles_1.retry'

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.10.1.94                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Request your help in debugging this.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an error message: _"Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed"_. Fix it by correcting `known_hosts` for jenkins user.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Can you please be more detail on how to do that or could you provide any reference link? will be helpful as I'm also facing the exact same issue